# Rails ci_reporter cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, rspec, continuous-integration

I want to use [ci_reporter](https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter) to generate report xml, and then let `jenkins` publish error message.

I added this into gemfile

```
gem "ci_reporter"
```

Put following code into **Rakefile**

```
require 'ci/reporter/rake/rspec'
task :rspec => 'ci:setup:rspec'
```

Created a task file and put following code in **lib/ci_report.rake**

```
namespace :ci do
  task :all => ['ci:setup:rspec', 'rspec']
end
```

Then typed `rake ci:all` in terminal, but it threw this error

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ci/reporter/rake/rspec
```

What did I miss?

### update

After searching, I still felt confused. However, I found anther gem called [rspec_junit_formatter](https://github.com/sj26/rspec_junit_formatter). It works perfectly!

Comment: 1. Have you tried run `rake` with `bundle exec`?  2. If the `gem "ci_reporter"` line in the Gemfile is inside any group like `group :test do` try to move it out from the group then run `bundle install` and then try again with your `bundle exec rake ...` command.

Comment: yeah, I did all of that. I switch to use this gem `rspec_junit_formatter`. It's perfect!